# Google Contact API in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gdata, google-contacts-api, gmail-api

Hi Guys am new to Google API. Can some one suggest a working tutorial or steps for fetching all Gmail contacts using Google contact API with android.

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty good: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Also, see the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html